# Reader never reading from `StdoutPipe`

Tags: go

I'm trying to read stdout from a long-running (blocking / shell-like) command with the ultimate goal of creating a sidecar process that Go can interact with.

I have the following MCVE:

```golang
func main() {
    var err error
    // Build the long-running command
    args := []string{"-i0", "-o0", "-e0", "/usr/local/bin/ipython"}
    cmd := exec.Command("stdbuf", args...)

    // Keep the stdin file descriptor open
    // Spawned command should block waiting for input
    _, err = cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Setup pipe of `Reader` type
    var stdoutBuf []byte
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Start the command
    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            // Asynchronously continue reading from stdout
            n, err := stdout.Read(stdoutBuf)
            fmt.Println(n)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(stdoutBuf)
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 2000)
        }
    }()

    // Block forever
    if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Semantically this approach seems like it would work. I would expect that `stdout.Read` would return something (`ipython` shell preamble), but `n` is always 0.

1. Why does `Reader.Read` in this example never read anything?
2. Somewhat related question: is there a way I can block on reading `StdoutPipe` if there is nothing to be read?

I don't think anything is wrong with the process itself (which would cause an invalid file descriptor read) because `Start` doesn't `panic` and it seem like `cmd.Wait` blocks forever.

Comment: The process may be buffering output.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering.

Comment: Hmm, this is a good suggestion. I tried wrapping the command in `stdbuf`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `Reader.Read` in this example never read anything?

Because you are reading into a buffer of size 0, which is what `var stdoutBuf []byte` creates. Instead, use something like:

```
stdoutBuf := make([]byte, 4096)
```

You may also want to use [`bufio`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/).

> Somewhat related question: is there a way I can block on reading `StdoutPipe` if there is nothing to be read?

`stdout.Read` already blocks, as is typical (though not required) for an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader):

> If **some data is available** but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more. [...] Implementations of Read are **discouraged from returning a zero byte count** with a nil error, except when len(p) == 0.